# How do I download many of the same pictures fewer times with html, css, jquery, etc.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a chess board consisting of 64 squares. In all these squares is a picture of the board piece as in a light or dark square picture. Also for formatting issues, a Clear knight is placed. I am using a `div` with a background picture (light or dark board piece) and a `img` in the div with various knight pics. In the pic below there are 1 past move night, 1 current move knight, and 61 clear knight pics on top of the 64 board pics.

**How do I download many of the same pics without downloading many of the same pics?**

Example:
[image]

A piece of the html that renders this is:

```
        <table id="game" class="gametable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="0"><div class="DarkBoard 0"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="1"><div class="LightBoard 1"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="2"><div class="DarkBoard 2"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="3"><div class="LightBoard 3"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="4"><div class="DarkBoard 4"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="5"><div class="LightBoard 5"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="6"><div class="DarkBoard 6"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>  
                    <td class="tdcls" id="7"><div class="LightBoard 7"><img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80"></div></td>
                </tr>
```

I have css rendering the board pics:

```
.LightBoard{background-image: url(http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/LightBoard.png);}
.DarkBoard{background-image: url(http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/DarkBoard.png);}
```

And the html for the Clear knight spacers:

```
<img class="playpiece" src="http://freethecube.com/kt/pics/KnightClear.png" alt="KnightClear" height="80" width="80">
```

**How do I download many of the same pics without downloading many of the same pics?**

I am uncertain if the browser will download the first instance of the picture and then assign like elements the same pic or if all those pictures are all downloading many times. I am essentially asking if there is plainly a more efficient way of doing it or am I worried about bandwidth for nothing. I would not be worried about it at all if I were not downloading 129 pictures with every refresh.

Before you down vote, please ask me to rephrase or elaborate further on a particular aspect of the question.

Comment: browsers should download the repeated pic once only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will automatically cache multiple requests for the same resource. Open the developer console (ctrl + shift + i) and look in the network tab to verify that. (Make sure you don't have "disable cache" checked).

Additionally, you may want to consider creating an [image sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for all those images. That will help reduce those many small network requests down into one larger one, which is currently a more efficient way to download resources over HTTP.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/spriting-img/ this will be handing in both loading and running the game. thx.

Answer (score 0):

The images will be cached by the browser and will only download once.